# Error in startActionMode, appcompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, contextual-action-bar, android-actionbaractivity

I used `SherlockActionBar` in my application, but after I began to use appcompat. And get error

"The method `startActionMode(ActionMode.Callback)` in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments `(PageFragment.ActionModeCallback)`"

in the raw

```
   mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(new ActionModeCallback());
```

Help me please, what I do incorrect?

Comment: Thanks for posting the code.  It's a bit long, though--can you please edit your question to include just the relevant parts?  @Gopal asked for the imports section, so I imagine you need to include that, and perhaps the specific function which is raising the error.  Only include the rest of the code if it's needed.

Comment: mActionMode = ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(new ActionModeCallback()); solution

Comment: @user3176367: you can post and accept your own answer.so that it can be helpful to others as well.people generally don't look at the comments.

Answer (score 17):

Just to improve readability, according to user3176367, the solution was to cast the result of `getActivity` to `ActionBarActivity`.

Here is the working code:

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).startSupportActionMode(new ActionModeCallback());
```

Comment: Thank @user3176367 instead. All I did was post his comment as an answer.